# how to create heatmap plot python base on dataframe of result football matchs?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, heatmap

i want to make a heatmap plot in python. my code only draw relate between home_score and away_score like this

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 10))
plt.matshow(df_match[['home_score','away_score']].corr(),fignum=f.number)
plt.xticks(range(df_match.select_dtypes(['number']).shape[1]), df_match.select_dtypes(['number']).columns, fontsize=14, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(range(df_match.select_dtypes(['number']).shape[1]), df_match.select_dtypes(['number']).columns, fontsize=14)
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
plt.title('Correlation Matrix', fontsize=16);
```

here is it's out put:
[image]

how can i make a heatmap with x is score of home team, y is score of away team ?

```
my df like this
home_score  away_score
0   0   0
1   4   2
2   2   1
3   2   2
4   3   0
... ... ...
43080   0   1
43081   1   0
43082   1   2
43083   0   1
43084   0   2
```

all i want is sth like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: As long as your data is well-formatted, it should be doable in `plt.matshow`, or `seaborn.heatmap`. Question is, do you have the data available to do that? If you want a heatmap where x-axis is the home team and y-axis is the away team, your dataframe would also need to store the home team and away team for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer. Your existing code plots the correlation using `plt.matshow`. As long as your data is well-formatted, it should be doable in `plt.matshow`, or `seaborn.heatmap`. Question is, do you have the data available to do that?

If you want a heatmap where x-axis is the home team and y-axis is the away team, your dataframe would also need to store the home team and away team for each row. Given that both teams are specified, you can simply store the score difference between both. Example below:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "score": [0, 4, -2, 2, -3, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -3, 2],
    "home_team": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "D", "D", "C", "D"],
    "away_team": ["B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B", "D", "D", "C", "A", "D", "B"]
})
```

If you can store your data in the format above, then you can use `df.pivot` to reshape your dataframe:

```
df2 = df.pivot(index="home_team", columns="away_team")
```

[image: Dataframe after pivot]

Then you can display the heatmap using either matplotlib or seaborn:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.matshow(df2)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib matshow]

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df2)
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn heatmap]